# Flutter retrofit response in xml

Tags: html, json, flutter, dart, dio

Im using dio+retrofit to hit a GET request on a particular website. I receive response in xml and an error:

```
DioError [DioErrorType.other]: RedirectException: Redirect loop detected
```

I'd like to make it work and receive this xml response then parse it to json/my app model.

The response should be in xml because im trying to scrap a website.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to decorate the http method causing error with

```
@DioResponseType(ResponseType.plain)
```

Here you can find a great article about xml parsing

https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-retrofit-and-xml-on-flutter-62faf9edfa3c